# Ubuntu /boot file full

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, dpkg, uninstall

I am running a Dell 1950 server with Ubuntu running on it.  I am getting a message that my /boot file is full.  I know that I have many older version images of the kernel installed and taking up space.  I have scoured the ubuntu sites for solutions.  I understand I have to remove these images.  I try to remove them but I am stuck as there "is not enough space" to do anything.

I run apt-get install -f and I get messages the there are unmet dependencies

I try installing Synaptic but I cannot install it

I am stuck.  Can someone help?

I listed below are the results of my efforts:

```
dell@ubuntu9:~$ uname -r
3.13.0-117-generic
dell@ubuntu9:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
[sudo] password for dell:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-121-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-128-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
dell@ubuntu9:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-100 linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-107 linux-headers-3.13.0-107-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-111 linux-headers-3.13.0-111-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-112 linux-headers-3.13.0-112-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-115 linux-headers-3.13.0-115-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-119 linux-headers-3.13.0-119-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-121 linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-107-generic linux-image-3.13.0-111-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic linux-image-3.13.0-115-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-107-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-111-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-115-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-119-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-121-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.13.0 linux-source-3.13.0 linux-tools
  linux-headers-3.13.0-121-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/30.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 357462 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic_3.13.0-128.177_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic (3.13.0-128.177) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic_3.13.0-128.177_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-3.13.0-128-generic' to '/boot/System.map-3.13.0-128-generic.dpkg-new': failed to wri                 te (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (B                 roken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-128-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-128-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-128-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-128-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic_3.13.0-121.170_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic (3.13.0-121.170) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic_3.13.0-121.170_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-3.13.0-121-generic' to '/boot/System.map-3.13.0-121-generic.dpkg-new': failed to wri                 te (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (B                 roken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-121-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-121-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic_3.13.0-128.177_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic_3.13.0-121.170_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
dell@ubuntu9:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-100 linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-107 linux-headers-3.13.0-107-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-111 linux-headers-3.13.0-111-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-112 linux-headers-3.13.0-112-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-115 linux-headers-3.13.0-115-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-119 linux-headers-3.13.0-119-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-121 linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-107-generic linux-image-3.13.0-111-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-112-generic linux-image-3.13.0-115-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-107-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-111-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-115-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-119-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-121-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.13.0 linux-source-3.13.0 linux-tools
  linux-headers-3.13.0-121-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic linux-image-3.13.0-128-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/30.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

I am not sure what to do now.  Please make a suggestion so I can try it.

Comment: Why not run `sudo apt-get autoremove` as suggested?

Comment: Start by following the last suggestion in the error message: `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: And... What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and kernel version 3.13.0-117-generic.  When I try to run the remove command I will not run, I get errors stating there is no disk space.  I receive an error code like this Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu Tweak, available from the Ubuntu Software centre, to remove old kernels and other items. Occasionally auto-update will report low disk space, so I run "Janitor" in the tweak settings to clear space.

PLEASE ENSURE YOU BACK-UP YOUR FILES BEFORE USING THIS.